# Installing Bootstrap through NPM in Laravel install

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, bootstrap-4, laravel-mix

I added Bootstrap in my package.json file like this `"bootstrap": "^4.3.1"` after that I typed `npm install` in the terminal and it completed without any errors. What's next? How can I add Bootstrap in my view? It seems that NPM installed Bootstrap to the /node_modules folder, but I also have the bootstrap.js file in resources/js/bootstrap.js.

Comment: Are you using Laravel Mix? With a Webpack build? https://laravel.com/docs/master/mix

Answer (score 9):

you can use Laravel mix to the compile your assets and then simply link that in your layout, so what you need to is import bootstrap in your `app.scss` you can do it like this,

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

and in you `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php` link that style file like this,

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

in laravel 5.6 or lesser versions `app.scss`file was located in `resources/assets/sass` but in laravel 5.7 and higher version it has been changed to `resources/sass/`. run `npm run dev`  in your project folder to generate the assets. hope this helps